# Deleted answer because no original content

Tags: discussion, answers, deleted-answers, specific-answer

[I posted what I thought was an answer for the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59038194/how-to-use-node-js-express-function-in-html-file/59038282?noredirect=1#comment104322324_59038282). The answer came from another web site. Rather than link to the site alone, I posted the relevant info on the page as well as the credit tag, as I thought proper.  I do not understand why it was crushed. Neither did I say just go to this site nor did I take the info from the page and try to make it look as though I were the originator of the thought.

Are we supposed to only post original works for answers or can we actually refer to existing knowledge?

Comment: Don't get fooled by Marks wrong answer. Even formatting the copied content makes your answer acceptable. Your answer must provide __your__ words/work and can be __supported__ by (properly formatted) content from other answers/site, including attribution.

Comment: Given that this is a specific-answer question, I think it will likely be 'duplicated' many more times. I am glad there was a forum to get my answers and I will of course internalize the lesson.  Feel free to delete the thread if you think it is of no value. I have the answers I needed.

Comment: @Tom See BoltClock's answer at the dupe, which disagrees with you: *"Granted, there are some situations where indeed there isn't much more to be said than one or two well-written paragraphs from a documentation section or a language specification. That's fine, you're not going to get into trouble for doing that every now and then. Just remember that you still need to provide attribution and quote the text"*. We tend to disapprove of quote-only answers and often downvote them accordingly, but as long as proper quoting and attribution is given and they are indeed answers, we don't delete them.

Comment: @MarkAmery I just highlight you two important parts, **"than one or two well-written paragraphs"** (maybe re-check how much OP copied) and **"from a documentation section or a language specification"** so that paragraph doesn't even apply to this case. It is meant for questions about why something works like it does and the answerer quotes the docu/lang specs, not for copying tutorials (but granted, BoltClock could just be really ambiguous about what they really meant with that)

Comment: Apologies for the ambiguity. I meant the deletion of this post in meta. If it's a dupe and brings no value then we should delete.  I feel the question about the post in stack was answered well and I agree with the mod's decision after it was explained here.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your answer was that you did not indicate clearly that the content was a quote. Even someone seeing "credit: https://www.guru99.com/node-js-express.html" at the bottom would not be able to tell that you had outright copied content from there, let alone that the entire technical content of your answer was copied.

Copying relevant content from other sources is fine. Even posting an answer that contains no original content is *tolerated* in practice, although some people disapprove of it. However, you need to clearly indicate that such content is not your work, typically by using quotation marks (if quoting a short phrase in the middle of a sentence) or block quote formatting, in addition to linking to the original source.

If your answer had looked like this, instead (which is a copy-and-paste of your answer with some block quote formatting and two words of extra prose added to clearly indicate that the content is copied), then it would almost certainly not have been deleted:

> You should, as many will tell you I am sure, say what you have tried
>   already. What is working and what isn't.    Here is a quick answer, taken from https://www.guru99.com/node-js-express.html:
>
> > [image]
> >
> > ```
> > var express=require('express');
> > var app=expzress();
> > app.get('/',function(req,res)
> > {
> >     res.send('Hello World!');
> > });
> > var server=app.listen(3000,function() {});
> > ```
> >
> > **Code Explanation:**
> >
> > 1. In our first line of code, we are using the require function to include the "express module."
> > 2. Before we can start using the express module, we need to make an object of it.
> > 3. Here we are creating a callback function. This function will be called whenever anybody browses to the root of our web application
> >        which is http://localhost:3000 . The callback function will be used to
> >        send the string 'Hello World' to the web page.
> > 4. In the callback function, we are sending the string "Hello World" back to the client. The 'res' parameter is used to send content back
> >        to the web page. This 'res' parameter is something that is provided by
> >        the 'request' module to enable one to send content back to the web
> >        page.
> > 5. We are then using the listen to function to make our server application listen to client requests on port no 3000. You can specify
> >        any available port over here.
> >
> > If the command is executed successfully, the following Output will be
> >     shown when you run your code in the browser.
> >
> > [image]
>
> I hope this gets you started.

We don't require that you "only post original works", but we *do* require that you don't post other people's content in a way that falsely gives the impression that it's your work. That's plagiarism, and against the rules here.

Comment: Even when citing from a site the license of that site has to be respected. The best thing I could find here is "© Copyright - Guru99 2019" which doesn't look as if reposting large parts of the content is allowed. I disagree with the statement that citing alone without adding any new content is fine.

Comment: @BDL We don't enforce third party licenses except in response to takedown requests, though. Even if an answer is knowingly and blatantly infringing on other people's copyright, until the moment that a takedown notice gets sent to Stack Overflow Inc that's nobody's business except the answerer, the person whose copyright is being infringed, their lawyer, and their priest.

Comment: I thought that anyone seeing the answer would click the link for more info and it would be obvious. However, I do understand, and agree in hindsight with, the issue you present here and appreciate the explanation.

Comment: It's one thing to say, "[w]e don't enforce third party licenses except in response to takedown requests" and another to encourage people to copy copyrighted works wholesale, as your answer explicitly does with the sentence "Copying relevant content from other sources is fine."

Comment: @HereticMonkey "Copying relevant content from other sources" is not synonymous with "copy[ing] copyrighted works wholesale". Nor does this case involve copying copyrighted works wholesale in the first place; the answer being discussed includes only about an eighth or so of the blog post it's taken from.